# From Ubuntu, "Back to my Mac"

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, dns, macosx

I have a Mac at home, and run Ubuntu at work. I'd like to be able to connect to my Mac in a similar way to how I had when I worked on a Mac. I have MobileMe so I used Back to My Mac (Apple's version to dynamic DNS) to connect and Screen Sharing (VNC) to access the screen.

My question is, what's the best way to recreate this setup so that I can do the same actions from Ubuntu?

Thank you.

Comment: There is [a question](http://superuser.com/questions/87728/how-do-i-get-back-to-my-mac-using-mobileme-from-windows) on Super User about making a similar connection from a Windows PC that may give some clues.

Comment: Thank you moberley. The tips there were indeed a good clue. I'm able to ssh between my Macs at home using those tips. Unfortunately, I'm unable to connect to them from my Ubuntu machine at work. Continuing to dig into this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are various dynamic dns services, of which dyndns is probably the most well known. The repos have a few packages to automatically update your dyndns for you if your IP changes: try the `dyndns' package.

Comment: as opposed to packages, there are also scripts to accomplish this very task.  it is not a unique problem and has been around for some time.  there are open source vnc products/packages/source bundles for mac to connect using VNC to ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

Can I be the poor beggar I am?

Teamviewer :)

Answer (score 0):

this is an old question, but why don't you try HIP for Linux [1]. You can run it together with miredo daemon [2] to support NAT traversal. Binaries for Ubuntu are available at the hipl.hiit.fi site.

[1] http://www.linuxjournal.com/magazine/host-identity-protocol-linux

[2] http://hipl.hiit.fi/hipl/manual/HOWTO.html#teredo